# How to make dot and comma sensation in GridView Textbox?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

i wanna put dot and comma sensation in GridView textbox, For example i have a textbox field in asp.net gridview it is money field. i have an input 1234 dollars and 50 cent. if i write 1234 => my keypress it should return it 1.234 after COMMA 1.234. i am pressing comma "," ) it should stop "." intellisense 1.234,50 cent. but it does not work properly.
if i start to write 
 on keyup should start to change it. it should start to change input to : (while writing) 
1234 dollars 50 centinput (123450) => 1.234,50
1234567 dollars 75 cent(1234567(you can put comma.it should not prevent)75) => 1.234.567,75)

My C# Code:

```
  private void GvRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            TextBox txtVeri = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtVeri");
            txtVeri.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "InsertComma(this.id)");

        }

    }
```

My JS code:

```
        function InsertComma(veriId) {
        console.log("çalışıyor");

        var txtObj = document.getElementById(veriId);
        var txtVal = replaceAll(txtObj.value, '.', '');
        //alert(txtObj.value);
        if (txtObj.value != "") {
            var newVal = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < txtVal.length; i++) {
                //alert(txtVal.substring(i, 1));
                newVal = newVal + txtVal.substring(i, i + 1);

                if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0 && i != 0 && i + 1 < txtVal.length) {
                    newVal = newVal + ".";
                }
            }
            txtObj.value = newVal;
        }

    }

    function replaceAll(txt, replace, with_this) {
        return txt.replace(new RegExp(replace, 'g'), with_this);
    }
```

Comment: "1234 dollars 50 cent" this is your input ?

Comment: No my input is 123450 should return = 1.234,50.it should give right putting comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your requirement please have a look on this example

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".btnSubmit").click(function () {
                var txtObj = $("#txtInput").val();
                if (txtObj.length != "") {
                    var newVal = "";
                    var arr = txtObj.split(' ');
                    if (arr[0].length >= 4) {
                        var doller = arr[0];
                        var cents = arr[2];
                        var decimal = ".";
                        var position = doller.length - 3
                        var output = [doller.slice(0, position), decimal, doller.slice(position)].join('') + "," + cents;
                        $("#txtInput").val(output);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtInput" value="1234 dollers 50 cents" /><br />
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btnSubmit" />
```

**Below code according to your comment**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".btnSubmit").click(function () {
                var txtObj = $("#txtInput").val();
                if (txtObj.length != "") {
                    var newVal = "";
                    var doller = txtObj;
                    if (doller.length >= 4) {
                        var decimal = ".";
                        var comma = ",";
                        var posDecimal = doller.length - (doller.length - 1);
                        var posComm = doller.length - 1;
                        var output = [doller.slice(0, posDecimal), decimal, doller.slice(posDecimal)].join('');
                        var FinalOutput = [output.slice(0, posComm), comma, output.slice(posComm)].join('');
                        $("#txtInput").val(FinalOutput)
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtInput" value="123450" /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btnSubmit" />
```

Comment: my input is 123450 should return = 1.234,50.it should give right putting comma

Comment: above edited code & logic are according to your condition, you can change logic according to your condition. :-)